# Dcoker command give error standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My dockerfile is like below:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN mkdir /app

COPY hello_there.py hello_cmd.py /app


CMD ["python","/app/hello_there.py"]
```

But whenever I am trying to run the container using below command:

```
docker run --name singada4 singada /app/hello_cmd.py
```

It is giving following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Both python file is there. I want to just overwrite CMD command with /app/hello_cmd.py while running the container.

Comment: Can you otherwise run `./hello_there.py`, without explicitly naming the `python` interpreter?  (Is it executable; does it begin with a `#!/usr/bin/env python3` "shebang" line?)

Comment: CMD ["python","/app/hello_there.py"] this one is working. But when I tried to run and overwrite the CMD from terminal with docker run --name singada4 singada /app/hello_cmd.py than it is giving the error. I just want to know the cause...